# Writing to a new line of a file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, escaping, nsfilehandle

For some strange reason, the \n and \r escape sequences do not seem to be working in my code.  I want to write each NSString on a new line of the file, but it just appends it the last string on one line.  Here's the code:

```
for (Entry *entry in self.entries) {
    NSString *path = @"/Users/me/File.txt";
    NSString *string = (@"%@\r\n", [entry thisEntry]);
    NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
    [fh seekToEndOfFile];
    [fh writeData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]];
    [fh closeFile];
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Forgive me as I am new to Objective-C.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
NSString *string = (@"%@\r\n", [entry thisEntry]);
```

It should be:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [entry thisEntry]];
```

Comment: Yup! That was it...seems to work perfectly.  Seems like a pretty dumb mistake on my part.  Thanks again!